# Change appearance of uitextfield

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I have a textfield I need to customize.
I want the border to only show on the bottom of the textfield (instead of a rectangle, I want a borderless textfield with just a line under the text).

What I tried :

In `viewDidLoad`, I tried changing the `.borderStyle` property, then noticed I could in IB
I looked at the .layer property.
tried to set a background image that would be white with a line on the bottom but there is no backgroundImage property or `textField.view` 
I tried creating a view and appending it to `textField.subViews (UIView[])`.

I tried sub-classing `UITextField`, that did not work (because I did not know what method to put the modifications in, if there even is one).

Answer (score 1):

The straight answer is it's not possible having border only at the bottom. But if you're deliberately looking for this behavior, you can try the following idea.

- Place the UITextfield in your viewcontroller.
- Choose the borderstyle as no border.
- Now select UIView and place it inside the view controller.
- Set the View's X,Y values bottom to your Textfield.
- And also set the width same as your Textfield, and height to 1px.
- Set the View's background color as you needed.

The idea is create a uiview which appears to be a line at the bottom of your UITextField. See the sample screen below.
[image: UITextField with only bottom border]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is Subclass UITextField and make your own version of it.
Override whichever method you will use to instantiate it such as initWithFrame or initWithCoder.  In those methods you can add a UIView with a height of 1 pixel and a width the size of the textfield to the bottom of the textfield as a subview, don't forget to set the views color!

So to be clear use init with frame if you are instantiating it yourself by calling:

```
[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame]
```

Or you can override

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```